# gfortran.exe: error: /usr/local/lib/liblapack.a: No such file or directory

Tags: windows, static-libraries, gfortran, lapack

I installed ubuntu and gfortran in my windows 11. I used Visual Studio Code to edit and terminal of VSC to compile gfortran. Everything is ok.
Now I download Lapack and install it in Ubuntu, but when compile gfortran with Lapack lib with:

```
C:\Users\minhh\Fortran\wk> gfortran testlapack.f90 /usr/local/lib/liblapack.a -o test
```

I receive error:

> gfortran.exe: error: /usr/local/lib/liblapack.a: No such file or directory

I check with command `ls /usr/local/lib/liblapack.a`.
It returns:
`/usr/local/lib/liblapack.a`.
This means liblapack.a installed in local lib.

Here the way I installed: 1. Install Ubuntu as Windows subsystem 2. Install Gfortran in Ubuntu 3. Install Visual Studio Code, use VSC to edit file .f90, use terminal of VSC to compile gfortran. Note that I can compile with many module in this terminal such as: gfortran a.f90 b.f90 c.f90 -o a But now can not get lapack lib even I check in Ubuntu that lapacklib is in \usr\local\lib

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Wait, you are in a Windows command prompt, but you are using Unix style directory paths `/usr/local/lib/liblapack.a`. What exactly are you using? Are you using Windows Subsystem for Linux or something else? What exactly? How did you install the library? Did you do it in Windows or in Linux? Where exactly is your Visual Studio code installed. Please be detailed and specific.

Comment: Be aware that `.a` is a Unix suffix for a library archive, not a Windows one. It is very very suspicious. Please tell as also where exactly you executed ` ls /usr/local/lib/liblapack.a`. Was it a windows terminal or WSL terminal? Be aware that Your VSC is using Windows Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the libraries (or any other software) installed in Ubuntu directly from your Windows, even if the Ubuntu happens to be in the Windows Subsystem for Linux. Even if the file could be accessed, the Windows linker will not understand the format of the Linux library.

You either have to install Lapack to Windows (it will be a .lib or a .dll) or you have to compile your code in Ubuntu.